# Ruby on Rails : How to use TCP socket to connect with GPS Device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, gps

**ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux],**
**Rails 4.2.4**

I am using cloud9 IDE and webrick server.
My project is to track GPS in real time.

I want to use TCP connection to communicate with GPS tracking device which requires to transmit data in hexa decimal format like 0x01.
 i put the following code in controller.

**GPS device protocol is confidential**. so i am unable to provide that here.

my server is running on port 8080. the device sending data to this port.

But i don't know how to write code to establish connection between our server and device and how to transmit and view the data sent by device to server.

i found something like this on net . i don't know whether is it correct or not.

```
 require 'socket'
    server = TCPServer.new ("127.0.0.1",8080)
    loop do
      Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
        client.puts "Hello !"
        client.puts "Time is #{Time.now}"
        client.close
      end
    end
```

But it causes following Error.

> Address already in use - bind(2) for nil port 8080

if i change it to another port it shows

> Bad Gatewat Error.502

Kindly help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the server need to query data from the device or does the device send data? Why does this need to happen when a browser requests a webpage? What do you expect as GPS location: The browsers? The servers? The location of the GPS device?

Comment: first device automatically sends login data to server once it switched on.after that server needs to query location of gps tracking device or engine status of vehicle it connected or alaram etc.device replies data accordingly  to server in hexa deci format.

Comment: If your rails app is receiving http connections on port 8080 then it cannot also listen for those non http connections on the same port.

Comment: @Fredrick Cheung then how to solve this ? if i chage port it shows bad gateway 502 Error

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve. You are already at implemention details. 
What device, how does it communicate? Why is this connected to a Rails action. How does the device know when it can open a connection?

Comment: @pascalbetz Benway Technologies GPS Tracking device which has sim slot.. it communicates through gprs by sending data to our server when we send query. i want to query device location and display it on our project to know vehicle status which got connected gps device.we have to query device to get reply from it.

Comment: So the application (server) needs to query the device for its location? Then the GPS device is actually a server and your application is a client for that particular part of the communication.
So you need to know the Address (IP) of the device in order to connect to it and query it.

But your code is the other way around: your server opens a port and is listening for devices that connect.

Comment: @pascalbetz edited question..please check the error

Comment: Please describe the setup. Who is the client, who is server. Why do you receive a HTTP error code when making a raw TCP connection? What are you connecting to?  127.0.0.1? That is your local host, not your GPS device.

As said multiple times before: describe the situation first.

Comment: @sriharisairamVentrapragada See my last comment

Comment: Hi @sriharisairamVentrapragada
I'm working with a similar setup, did you find a way? I'm thinking about having a separate ruby tcp server instead of including it with the Rails app.