# How to use TCPServer in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tcp

I am using Ruby on Rails on Cloud9 IDE

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
 $ rails -v
Rails 4.2.4
```

I have to transmit data between server and GPS device. I put on device and did code like below.

**My_Controller**

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!


       def index

        require 'socket'
        server = TCPServer.new ("127.0.0.1",8000)
        loop do
          Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
            client.puts "Hello !"
            client.puts "Time is #{Time.now}"
            client.close
          end
        end
        @bookings = Booking.where(user: current_user).joins(:customer, :driver, :car)
        @customers = Customer.where(user: current_user)
       end
end` ****
```

when i ran this i got

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'> 
    <title>Error 502 - Bad Gateway</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.c9.io/errors/style.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    .error_content {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.23);
        padding: 10px;
        width: 641px;
        margin: 25px 0;
        display: none;
    }

    #error-msg {
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="errorUnknown light">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <h1>Error 502 - Bad Gateway</h1>
      <div class="error_content" id="error-msg">
          <p>Please click <a href="javascript:location.reload(true)">here</a> to try again, if the issue persists please contact <a href="https://c9.io/support">support</a></p>
      </div>

      <a href="http://status.c9.io">Status Page</a> |
      <a href="https://c9.io/support">Support</a> |
      <a href="https://c9.io/dashboard.html">Dashboard</a> |
      <a href="https://c9.io">Home</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Kindly, help me how to solve this problem..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your Rails app is already running on a TCP server, otherwise you were not able to open a page in a browser. That means you tried to start a TCP server in a request to another TCP Server. Furthermore that server is running in a loop and will never return... My advise is: Close this question and start a new one and explain what you try to achieve. What kind of data needs to transferred in what direction, what documentation do you have? This looks like a [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me.

Comment: ok..i will do it. how to view data (it is in hexa decimal ) receiving by our server(we brick) from device

Comment: This seems to be the follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284765/ruby-on-rails-how-to-use-tcp-socket-to-connect-with-gps-device

Answer (score 2):

You go into an endless loop in the action. The request from the reverse proxy to your rails server times out. The reverse proxy sends an error message (502) to the browser.

Comment: Then no client connects to 127.0.0.1:8080 and the ^accept`call blocks, i assume.

Follow @spickermann's advice and open a new question where you describe what you want to achieve. Your current solution looks broken.

Comment: okay.please tell me how to view data (it is in hexa decimal ) receiving by our server(we brick) from GPS device